# issues with Formatdate function in ampscript

Tags: salesforce, amp-html, formatdatetime, ampscript

I have an issue where I want to display only the hh.mm in da-DK from the `NOW()` function in AMPscript.
I have tried the following two options.

```
formatdate(Now(),"","HH.mm","da-DK")
```

This inputs only time but servertime, ex. 03.16

```
format(Systemdatetolocaldate(Now()),"","hh.mm")
```

Correct time but the whole string, ex. 12/10/2020 10:16:44 AM

Anyone with some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a "quickfix" with the set of

```
SET @redeemedHour = datePart(Systemdatetolocaldate(Now()),"H")
SET @redeemedMinute = datePart(Systemdatetolocaldate(Now()),"minute")
```

and then concanate